# Looking for tiles to construct modern city in 2D quest

Tags: games, tiles

I want to develop a simple 2D quest and for doing that i need a tilepack for modern city. I googled for some sites with tileas, but I don't found anything interesting (all that I found is a few common tilepacks).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try stock sites like Shutterstock, with different searching keywords,

[for example](http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?searchterm=city%20tile&search_group=&lang=en&search_source=search_form)

If you need a whole set, probably you should work with some graphic/mobile designer directly.